# Apache Camel processor secure configuration

Tags: apache-camel

I have a processor that logs into a database, and tags a message based on info there and in the message.

The question is what is the best way to set the connection string for the processor so that it is secure?

Right now I am loading a .cfg file in a spring blueprint xml, and binding it to properties in the processor with the bind annotation. But I'm wondering if there is a better, more secure way to do it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Maybe post the processor implementation.

Comment: That is not a Camel question as its all how you connect to the database and how that is configured. If the database / jdbc driver etc supports secure connection - then lookup in that vendors documentation how to do that.

Comment: @clausisben This is not about supplying the credentials to the database, but to the processor that accesses it.

Comment: The processor is just Java, so you can pass it in as constructors, getter/setters etc. And create an instance of the processor which you use in the Camel route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a new bean specifically for retrieving core configuration information, and then just using `@BeanInject`, or just passing it in as a class argument, for the classes that needed it.

Now I can handle the security of it how I want (or at least, much better than before), and if I want, I can easily replace/alter it to pick up settings from a trusted central server instead if need be.